# Convert SQL para Mongodb

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

--Pessoal peco ajuda para converter a seguinte query do sql para o mongodb:

```
select count(*)
FROM tabela Where ((DataFim - DataInicio  ) /1000 /60 /60) is not null and  ((DataFim - DataInicio ) /1000 /60 /60) > 1 and  ((DataFim - DataInicio ) /1000 /60 /60) < 2;
```